# How to run Laravel artisan command without using command line

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a `Laravel package` that will use a custom artisan command i.e `php artisan make:baserepository User -c`. `-c` means I will create a `controller` as well.

I want when I run this artisan command, I am able to create a `controller`. Here is my code that creates the controller.

```html
protected function createController() {
     $modelsingular = Str::singular(Str::ucfirst($this->getNameInput()));
     $modelplural = Str::plural($modelsingular);

     $controller = Str::studly(class_basename($this->argument('name')));
     $modelName = $this->qualifyClass($modelplural . '/' . $modelsingular);

     $this->call('make:controller', [
            'name' => "{$modelplural}\{$controller}Controller",
            '--model' => $this->option('resource') ? $modelName : null,
     ]);
}
```

Take a look at this line `'name' => "{$modelplural}\{$controller}Controller"`. I want the controller to be like this `Admin\Admin.php` in `Http\Controllers`, instead I am getting `Admin\{Admin}Controller.php`. Where am I getting it wrong?

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Try concatenating the string with the point `'name' => $modelplural.'\'.$controller.'Controller'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@porloscerros comment helped me solve my problem, Here is how I did it

```html
protected function createController() {
     $modelsingular = Str::singular(Str::ucfirst($this->getNameInput()));
     $modelplural = Str::plural($modelsingular);

     $controller = Str::studly(class_basename($this->argument('name')));
     $modelName = $this->qualifyClass($modelplural . '/' . $modelsingular);

     $this->call('make:controller', [
            'name' => $modelplural.'\'.$controller.'Controller',
            '--model' => $this->option('resource') ? $modelName : null,
     ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call your command with `Artisan::call()` function

As an example:

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('email:send', [
        'user' => 1, '--queue' => 'default'
    ]);
});
```

The original doc can be found here: [Artisan #calling-commands-via-code](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#calling-commands-via-code)

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = 'there';

echo "hi\{$a}";
// hi\{there}
```

The `\` before the `{` is the issue here.

```
echo "hi\\{$a}";
// hi\there
```

Now we are escaping the `\` as `\\`.

```
"{$modelplural}\\{$controller}Controller"
// Admin\AdminController
```